# How recompute the eltype of a vector in Julia

Tags: julia

Let's say I have a vector
`v = Any[1,2,3,4]`

And I would like to recompute its eltype in such a way that
`typeof(v) = Vector{Int}`

Is it possible to accomplish this without having to manually concatenate each of the elements in `v`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't "retype" the existing `v`, just create a copy of it with the more concrete type<sup>1</sup>.

### Conversion

Assuming you already (statically) know the result type, you have multiple options.  Most readable (and IMO, idiomatic) would be

```
Vector{Int}(v)
```

which is almost equivalent to

```
convert(Vector{Int}, v)
```

except that the latter does not copy if the input types is already the target type.  Alternatively:

```
convert.(Int, v)
```

which surely copies as well.

### What to convert to

If you *don't* know what the "common type" would be, there are multiple options how to get one that matches.  In general, [typejoin](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.typejoin) can be used to find a least upper bound:

```
mapreduce(typeof, typejoin, v; init=Union{})
```

The result will most likely be abstract, e.g. `Real` for an array of `Int`s and `Float64`s.  So, for numeric types, you might be better off with [`promote_type`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/base/#Base.promote_type):

```
mapreduce(typeof, promote_type, v; init=Union{})  # or init=Number
```

This at least gives you `Float64` for mixed `Int`s and `Float64`s.

But all of this is not really recommended, since it might be fragile, surprising, and is certainly not type stable.

---

<sup>1</sup>For certain combinations of types, with compatible binary form, [`reinterpret`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reinterpret) will work and return a view with a different type, but this is only possible for bits types, which `Any` is not. For converting `Any[1,2,3]` to `Int[1,2,3]` copying is fundamentally necessary because the two arrays have different layouts in memory: the former is an array of pointers to individually allocated integers objects, whereas the latter stores the `Int` values inline in contiguous memory.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for the edit, I took this for granted.

Comment: A small comment is that `Vector{Int}(x)` will always copy `x` while `convert(Vector{Int}, x)` will not copy if `x` already has the type you want to convert to.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the output type, then consider using a comprehension

```
foo(v) = [x for x in v]
```

This is considerably faster on my computer than `identity.(v)`:

```
julia> v = Any[1,2,3,4];

julia> @btime foo($v);
  153.018 ns (2 allocations: 128 bytes)

julia> @btime identity.($v);
  293.908 ns (5 allocations: 208 bytes)

julia> @btime foo(v) setup=(v=Any[rand(0:9) for _ in 1:1000]);
  1.331 μs (2 allocations: 7.95 KiB)

julia> @btime identity.(v) setup=(v=Any[rand(0:9) for _ in 1:1000]);
  25.498 μs (494 allocations: 15.67 KiB)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick and dirty trick that usually solves the problem

```
julia> v = Any[1,2,3,4]
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> identity.(v)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```